# Rails 4: self.update not working inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up a simple soft delete system by adding a `before_destroy` callback which sets the deleted flag and then returns false (to prevent real destroy from happening).

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    before_destroy :soft_delete

    def soft_delete
        self.update( is_deleted: 1 )
        false
    end

end
```

This does *not* result in the record getting updated. I'm not sure why. I see `[1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m` in my logs, but I'm not sure it's relevant or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the
>   associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false,
>   all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in
>   the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as
>   methods on the model, which are called last.

Comment: So my strategy will not work because the return of `false` undoes the update which sets the flag. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it won't proceed. I guess you should move your logic to your controller. Or maybe search if there is a good thing to do overriding the model's destroy method.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `self.update_columns(is_deleted: true)` may work...

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`self.update_attributes(is_deleted: 1)`

Worked for me on **Rails 4.2.4**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest overriding the destroy method directly in the controller. As always, try to follow rails' best practice of "Fat model skinny controller". I'd make the bulk of the logic in the Model, and then simply call it from the controller like this:

In your model:

```
def soft_delete!
    update_attribute(:is_deleted, 1)
    #remove any other attributes you want here (ie. if there are tasks associated with projects and such they should also be cascade "soft deleted here"
end
```

In your controller:

```
def destroy
   @project = Project.find(params[:id])
   @project.soft_delete!
   redirect_to projects_path
end
```

Something like that would work - on top of this, you may want to:

- Make soft_delete return boolean value so you can switch on it in controller and redirect to other places
- Soft delete other related attributes in other models (where I added the comment)

Comment: Essentially, I don't think using a before_destroy is the best way of achieving what you want :).